# Configuring Tomcat Monitoring

Tags: tomcat, monitoring, nagios

With `Check_JMX plugin` i am having the `javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURLClassNotFound` error. I have added the supported jar's to classpath . Also i am having the same issue.
I am using now java1.4 version Can we use java version 1.4 with JMX ?

How to solve the `javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL` class not found ?

Comment: Please have a look at the following thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462354/tomcat-5-5-monitoring-with-jdk-1-4-on-windows