# How to identify java heap size in 1.4

Tags: java, jvm-arguments, java1.4

I am running Java 1.4 (java version "1.4.2_08")

I wanted to know what is the current heap size of `JVM` .

When I ran below command

```
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|                                                                                        PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
```

I get this error:

```
Unrecognized VM option '+PrintFlagsFinal'
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

I gone through some articles, and came to know this command in not supported by Java 1.4 version.

Comment: That flag is most likely unavailable in java 1.4, it worked fine for me on 8

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: "*I am running Java 1.4*" - It has been a long time since I heard this name. You should really update to a more recent version, e.g. Java 1.6. This is the oldest version i know of that is still actively maintained (in this case by Azul Systems through OpenJDK).

Comment: @user1516873 , One of my customer has its application which runs on 1.4 and causing performance issue and causing out of memory error. To debug further , I wanted to what is  the heap size of this JVM . I am clueless how to proceed.

Comment: By maybe telling that customer that anything in IT has an end of life date. Java 1.4 had that many many many years in the past. Maybe, slowly prepare that customer for the sad news: "time to say good bye to that setup". When you have an isolated setup with no external interfaces, then yeah, keep it running while it doesnt cause terrible problems. Maybe they hit that "terrible problem" spot by now. It doesn't matter what exactly makes such a setup go away, sooner or later they will hit more and more issues.

Comment: And worse, 1.4.2_08 is not even the latest 1.4.2...

Comment: In any case, you'd normally derive the maximum heap size from the JVM arguments, if nothing is specified, it uses the default, which for non-server JVM is 64 megabytes (although it might have been 32MB back then for 1.4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to dig this up:
http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2008/09/05/profiling-your-java-142-memory-heap/

The part you are probably interested in:

> The key is to have your app do a heap dump when sending it the QUIT signal. Append this option to your java options on startup of your application:
>
> ```
> -XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak
> ```

After that, you need to send it a SIGQUIT (`kill -3 <PID>`). It will dump the heap to a file and you can go to town on that.

But please consider upgrading.

Comment: FYI: OP can't downvote: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: thanks @Z4-tier , I  can now able to see heap size by running this command     
  ps -elf | grep -i --color xmx

Answer (score 2):

As per [Ergonomics in the 5.0 Java TM Virtual Machine](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/ergo5-140223.html), if you haven't specified `-Xms` or `-Xmx` arguments in the Java 1.4 process command line it will be between 4 MB and 64 MB:

> In the J2SE platform version 1.4.2 by default the following selections were made
>
> - Serial garbage collector
> - Heap sizes
> - initial heap size of 4 Mbyte
> - maximum heap size of 64 Mbyte
> - Client runtime compiler

You could try to install the [JMX extension for Java 1.4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4246294/1602555) to get the runtime values but unfortunately it seems that the download is no longer available from the official Oracle website.

Without JMX extension you can't use JConsole, [as per docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html):

> Applications that are not attachable, with the management agent disabled. These include **applications started on a Java SE 1.4.2 platform** or started on a Java SE 5.0 platform without the `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` or `com.sun.management.jmxremote.port` options.

You are doing archaeology. I think you should accept that you won't get a perfect answer and just see how much memory is operating system allocating to the JVM process.